# Incorrect syntax near 'Case'. Expecting ID, QUOTED_ID, or '.' Error in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, backend

I multiple tables in my database. All of my tables are showing output using select query instead of only 1 table "case". it also have data and columns but when I use it in my query it shows syntax error. I have also attached picture which have list of table and a simple query. This code is not developed by me so I am not sure why it is showing error. Is there any kind of restriction we can set so that it cannot be used in queries?

[image: List o]

Comment: Note that SSMS is colour-coding the statement for you - that's a really big clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reserved words are not recommended for use as a database, table, column, variable, or other object names. If you desire to use a reserved word is used as an object name in ANSI standard syntax, it must be enclosed in double-quotes OR "[]" to allow the Relational Engine (whichever that one is) that the word is being used as an object and not as a keyword in the given context. Here is the sample code.

```
SELECT * FROM dbo."Case"
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[Case]
```

Comment: Exactly perfect answer. Solved my problem. Thanks Mate!

Answer (score 4):

`CASE` is a reserved keyword in SQL Server.  Therefore, you must escape it in double brackets:

```sql
SELECT * FROM dbo.[Case];
```

But best naming practice dictates that we should avoid naming database objects using reserved keywords.  So, don't name your tables `CASE`.

Comment: Exactly perfect answer. Solved my problem. Thanks Mate!